# Validation of radio buttons with a dynamic name

Tags: jquery

How can I check validation of all the radio buttons? Each question must be checked.

```
<td>QA02</td>
<td>The administrative staff is friendly.</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="QA02" value="1"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name=QA02 value="2"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name=QA02 value="3"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name=QA02 value="4"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name=QA02 value="5"></td>

<td>QA03</td>
<td>The administrative staff shows professionalism in their work.</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="QA03" value="1"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name=QA03 value="2"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name=QA03 value="3"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name=QA03 value="4"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name=QA03 value="5"></td>
```

Answer (score 3):

I gave id to the table to make it address particular part of page.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/qx8kx/3/)**

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    validationSuccess = true;
    $('#tbl tr td:nth-child(1)').each(function() {
        var group = $(this).text();
        if ($('[name=' + group + ']:checked').length == 0) {
            alert(group + "is not selected");
            validationSuccess = false;
        }
    });
    if(validationSuccess)
    {
        alert("Validation successful");
    }
});​
```

Comment: `var group` please... Globals are nasty. And I'd quote the value of `name` just to be on the safe side.